# How do i convert this Mod_rewrite rule to nginx

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

This is the Htacces rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ir.php?id=$1
```

how should I pass it to a Nginx compliant rewrite rule... i read the doc and did this:

```
rewrite ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ir.php?id=$1 last;
```

But didnt work.
and another question:
Is there any equivalent of .htaccess to Nginx (per directory rules)
Thanks

Comment: Finally, could solve it...

rewrite ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ir.php?id=$1 last;
To
rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /ir.php?id=$1 last;

Comment: +1 For figuring it out yourself, you might want to post your solution as an answer to your question and accept it so others with a similar problem can find it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, could solve it... rewrite ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ir.php?id=$1 last; To rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /ir.php?id=$1 last;

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your second question: no, there is no equivalent for Apache's .htaccess files for per directory configuration. You **can** have per directory configuration files included via the master config, **but** Nginx would need to be reloaded every time a config include file changed.